# How do I simplify the answer?

Tags: calculus

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\dfrac{\sin⁡(2x-0.1)}{\sqrt{1+x}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x}\cdot 2\cos⁡(2x-0.1)-\sin⁡(2x-0.1)\cdot\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}}{1+x}$$

I got that far but the answer at the back of the book gives the following...

$$\dfrac{2(1+x)\cos⁡(2x-0.1)-\dfrac{1}{2}\sin⁡(2x-0.1)}{\sqrt{1+x}^3}$$

How do I simplify to that form? Do I sub out the $\sqrt{1+x}$ in the numerator from the 1st 2 phrases? I'm not sure how to proceed please advise.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your derivation: the denominator is not right (there should not be a square root).

Comment: Apologies, typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}$.

Edit: This will work after you correct your derivative (see the comment by Clement C.)

Comment: I believe even that will not work without first correcting the derivative -- as it is, the two expressions given are *not* equal.

Comment: I think downvoting this answer is not helpful, because the answer is itself helpful. Clearly the OP is having issues with the step given by the hint - the incorrect derivative is, in a certain sense, circumstantial.

Comment: @user1729 That's arguable (although I agree on the non-downvoting): presumably, the OP could have tried that, and seeing that it failed didn't know if there was another "trick" to apply. More pragmatically, one could expect the users to try their hints before posting them, to see if they do work.

Comment: @ClementC. I agree on all counts.

Comment: You are right. I should have tried it myself, but I only did so in my head. My mental arithmetic seems to be a bit off, I must be getting old. EDIT: my hint does work, if I am not mistaken again, if the derivative is correct.

Comment: This might seem like a silly question but just want to be sure, you can do that to a fraction at anytime? when you change numerator you apply the same change to the denominator and vice versa? Thanks

Comment: You can always multiply the numerator and the denominator by the same factor (in this case $\sqrt{1+x}$). You cannot do the same with addition and subtraction or exponentiation!

Comment: ...assuming $x\neq-1$...

Comment: You are very much right. Any factor that isn't 0.